# Open MenuItem URL in iFrame in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iframe, menuitem

I have a dynamically generated menu (C#), like this:

`MenuItem(string text, string value, string imageUrl, string navigateUrl, string target)`

`MenuItem AdminLevel1 = new MenuItem("Admin", "Admin"); 
MenuItem AdminPedidosRegisto = new MenuItem("Questions", "AdminQ");

NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Messages Received", "AdminMessagesR", "", "./Admin/Messages.ascx", "ContainerIframe")); 
AdminPedidosRegisto.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem("Pending", "AdminPending", "", "./Admin/Pedidos.ascx", "ContainerIframe"));`

Where 'ContainerIframe' is the iFrame's ID and 'NavigationMenu' is the (asp:Menu)'s ID.

I want the URL in navigateUrl to open in an iFrame. Is that possible? If i set the iFrame's ID in the target parameter, in google chrome it works fine, but not in the other browsers. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you have any live version of your page ? This have to do with the way the javascript open the page, and how you send it inside the iframe.

Comment: Javascript? I don't have any javascript. I set the URL in navigateUrl parameter, and the iframe's ID in the target parameter, both in code behind. The menu is dinamic. I don't have a live version

Comment: The menu is dynamic by asp.net, so the javascript is also dynamic by the menu control. Do you use the asp.net menu control ? Can you point it out on msdn ?

Comment: I'll show you part of the code:

`MenuItem AdminLevel1 = new MenuItem("Administração", "Admin");
MenuItem AdminPedidosRegisto = new MenuItem("Pedidos de Registo", "AdminPedidosRegisto");
NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Mensagens Recebidas", "AdminMensagensRecebidas", "", BaseURL + "./Admin/Messages.ascx", "ContainerIframe"));
AdminPedidosRegisto.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem("Em Curso", "AdminPedidosRegistoEmCurso", "", BaseURL + "./Admin/Pedidos.ascx", "ContainerIframe"));`

Comment: Yes @Aristos , i use the ASP Menu control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `name` of the iframe and not the `id` to archive that, to load the page inside the iframe.

eg:

```
<iframe src="whatever.htm" id="whateverid" name="ContainerIframe"></iframe>
```

You can have the same id and name, but the important here is the `name`

Here is an iframe test that work: http://jsfiddle.net/7AMjy/3/

Comment: Thank you @Aristos. I'll post another question, see if you can help me please